# basic flow to develop the magento 2.0 admin module

Tags: magento, magento2

i have to develop one custom admin module.can you please suggest the basic flow to achieve this.what pre concepts we have to be familiar with for basic custom admin module.please let me know any reference links.

Comment: You need to go read the documentation and do some tutorials. Then when you get down to actually coding, and you get stuck, then come back and ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on these excellent references:

- [http://devdocs.magento.com](http://devdocs.magento.com/)
- [https://mage2.pro](https://mage2.pro/)
- http://alankent.me

Regards,

Comment: thanks fernando.But i am expecting a little breif explanation regarding admin module development as i am beginner to magento ,i just know the basics of magento